# Why input type="file" not working on browser

Tags: java, html, myeclipse

I just write a code for sending a mail using Java mail API on MyEclipse. For Attachment I used

```
 <input type="file" name="attachment"/>
```

On MyEclipse my code run and mail sent successfully but if I tried it on browser(like `mozila`,`chrome`) the whole path  of attachment (like: `D:/newfolder/img.png`) is not selected, only `filename` is selected (like: `img.png`).

That Cause an error/Exception:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: img.png (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Is there any alternate way to attach or upload file ..?

Comment: The path is informational only, you've supposed to use the *uploaded* file.

Comment: Show more of your code, including the `form` tag, and explain where you see the filename as selected and why that would matter. It sounds like your `form` tag lacks the `enctype` attribute, and this means that the selected file will not be included in the form data (only the name of the file, which is generally useless).

Comment: Can you post your complete HTML form code ?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the file, the file will be sent in the POST request and you can read all the content and the file name, but the original path will not be available to the server.

Following the specifications of HTML5, file paths are hidden by default in some browsers, notably Internet Explorer 8+ and some versions of Mozilla Firefox.

This is considered a security feature of the browser, but adding the site in question to the "Trusted Sites" list in the browser's configuration will allow the full path to be disclosed.

I found this on: [barracuda](https://www.barracuda.com/support/knowledgebase/50160000000IUwkAAG)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten this `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="upload_file.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are trying to open a file on the server that was uploaded from the client.

You have to read the incoming bytes from the request, and save it somewhere on disk or in a database.

The file name you see is strictly to help you define a name to save the file on server. You can't access the client file by reading the path directly.